# Calculate number of active customers each month for last 12 months

Tags: sql

I have a data set that includes customer id, sign up date and cancel date. I want to create a table that shows active customers at the 1st of every month for the past 12 months.

[image: Here's a screen shot of my data]

I have tried using [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761170/daily-count-of-active-users-for-a-given-date-range/27767946) question but couldn't work it out.

It would be great if the table had a 'month' column and a column for number of active customers.

Any help welcome, please.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...? The answer is likely to be database-specific.

Comment: Is that sample table data or the expected result? We want both anyway - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: How can you have customers that have cancelled before the signed up?

Comment: I would say missed in oversight while populating sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit* - Working example with Sql Server

1. you will ideally need here is a date/calendar table in Database with all the possible dates ( using this [Get all dates between two dates in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290454/get-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-sql-server)
   )
2. then join with it to find all the possible dates/month between a customer signup date and cancel date (with some conditions based on whether you treat a customer as active in a month if he cancelled on 1st of that particular month OR is a customer considered active in a certain month if he signed up late or in middle of that month)
3. NULLs means there is no cancellation date yet for the customer which means he is very much active.

   ```
   WITH cust (customerid,signupdate,canceldate) 
   AS 
   (SELECT 1, '2019-02-10' , '2020-03-05' UNION
    SELECT 2, '2018-12-01' , '2019-12-29' UNION
    SELECT 3, '2014-04-15' , '2019-09-15' UNION
    SELECT 4, '2019-02-10' , '2020-01-04' UNION
    SELECT 5, '2020-02-10' ,  NULL        UNION
    SELECT 6, '2019-07-10' , '2018-01-01' UNION
    SELECT 7, '2019-09-10' , '2020-05-01' UNION
    SELECT 8, '2019-02-06' ,  NULL        UNION
    SELECT 9, '2018-02-10' , '2020-07-29' UNION
    SELECT 10, '2020-02-10' , '2020-04-01' 
   )

   Select CONVERT(CHAR(6),cal.record_date,112) as yyyymm , 
          COUNT(DISTINCT c.customerid) as Active_Custs
   FROM tbl_Calendar cal
   JOIN CUST c ON CONVERT(CHAR(6),cal.record_date,112) BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),cast(c.signupdate as date),112) and CONVERT(CHAR(6),ISNULL(cast(c.canceldate as date),getdate()),112) 
   GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(6),cal.record_date,112)
   ORDER BY 1

   yyyymm  Active_Custs
   202007  1
   202006  1
   202005  4
   202004  5
   202003  6
   202002  6
   202001  5
   ```

Comment: Glad it has helped you. Please consider voting up the answer as well as it matters in SO.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Postgres, you can use something like this:

```
select to_char(g.dt::date, 'yyyy-mm'),
       count(c.customer_id) as active_customers
from generate_series(date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '11 month', date_trunc('month', current_date), interval '1 month') as g(dt)
  left join customer c on daterange(c.signup_date, cancel_date) @> g.dt::date
group by to_char(g.dt::date, 'yyyy-mm')
order by 1
```

This assumes that `customer_id = 6` in your sample data is an error as it has a signup_date that lies **after** the cancellation date.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=96b880269ac20cfac1ae3e7173b9a7d7)